# How can I find max number among numbers in this code?

Tags: python

```
class student(object):

    def student(self):
        self.name=input("enter name:")
        self.stno=int(input("enter stno:"))
        self.score=int(input("enter score:"))
    def dis(self):
        print("name:",self.name,"stno:",self.stno,"score:",self.score)
    def stno(self):
        return self.stno
    def name(self):
        return self.name
    def score(self):
        return self.score


y=[]
j=0
while(j<3):
    a=student()
    a.student()
    y.append(a)
    j+=1


for st in y:
    st.dis()

for b in y:
    max_v=b.score
    if max_v<b.score:
        max_v=b.score
print(max,b.stno,b.score)
```

I write above code, but I think there is a problem with finding maximum number amongst numbers as I am trying this code and I cannot find any solution for that. Do you have any opinion to improve this part of code. 
Many Thanks

Comment: You have created only one student and called it a.  You need to create more students, and populate their score with different values.  Each time you create a student, add it to a list of students.  I think you are trying to do that with `y`.  Use better names.  It will make it easier to understand your code.  Come back with better code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [Rawing's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38352832/189134) answer, but instead of a lambda, you can use `operator.attrgetter()`

```
from operator import attgetter

class ...
    # You class code remains unchanged

y=[]
j=0
while(j<3):
    a=student()
    a.student()
    y.append(a)
    j+=1


max_student = max(y, key=attrgetter('score'))
print("Highest score:", max_student.name, max_student.score)
```

Produces output like this:

```
enter name:dan
enter stno:3
enter score:3
enter name:emily
enter stno:20
enter score:20
enter name:frank
enter stno:1
enter score:1
Highest score: emily 20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function with a custom key function:

```
b = max(y, key=lambda student: student.score)
print(b.stno, b.score)
```

Answer (score 1):

The max for loop should be like this:

```
# works only with non-negative numbers
max_val = 0
for b in y:
    if max_val < b.score:
        max_val = b.score
```

or use the `max` function as [Rawing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222951/rawing) suggested.

-- Edited as Jim suggested

Comment: You shouldn't use names like `max` because they mask the corresponding built-in function `max`. Use something more indicative, like `max_val` instead.

Comment: You are right. That was copy paste from the original code.

Answer (score 1):

```
for b in y:
    max = b.score
    if man < b.score:
        max = b.score
```

You assign `max` to `b.score`, and in the next line you check `if man < b.score`.

1. If this is your actual code, `man` is not defined anywhere so you will get a `NameError`.
2. If this is not your actual code and just a typo and `man` is `max`, and in your code it is `if max < b.score` then this if will always be `False`, as you just assigned `b.score` to `max` in the line above.

Either way, why don't you simply use the built-in `max` function?

```
print(max(y, key=lambda student_obj:student_obj.score))
```