# how can I use remove for this code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
class student(object):

    def student(self):
        self.name=input("enter name:")
        self.stno=int(input("enter stno:"))
        self.score=int(input("enter score:"))
    def dis(self):
        print("name:",self.name,"stno:",self.stno,"score:",self.score)
    def stno(self):
        return self.stno
    def name(self):
        return self.name
    def score(self):
        return self.score


y=[]
j=0
while(j<3):
    a=student()
    a.student()
    y.append(a)
    j+=1


for st in y:
    st.dis()

n=int(input("enter #:"))
for c in y:
    if c.stno==n:
        y.remove(c.stno)


for st in y:
    st.dis()
```

I want to remove one of the students with his/her student number and score via student number. I write:

```
n=int(input("enter #:"))
for c in y:
    if c.stno==n:
        y.remove(c.stno)
```

But obviously there is a problem with that. Do you know have can I modify that to use remove or del or pop, although I think pop or del cannot be workable as there is no index?

Comment: It looks like your classmate is also asking questions about this assignment (though different ones): http://stackoverflow.com/q/38352723/189134

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just call

`y.remove(c)`

when you do `c.stno` it won't exist in the list because what is actually in the list is the object itself not it's attributes

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: `c.stno` returns the student number, when you call `y.remove(c.stno)`, you're trying to remove a value (stno) which doesn't exist in the list...remember it was the `student` object you appended to the list the `student` object contains the values not the list, the three elements in the list are the student objects

Answer (score 1):

It's not good to change the array you are iterating. You can try this:

```
for item in [c for c in y if s.stdno==n]:
    y.remove(item)
```