# how can I use remove for this code(2)?

Tags: python

In the [last code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356276/how-can-i-use-remove-for-this-code/38356363?noredirect=1#comment64125658_38356363) , I tried to use one array to remove information.

In this one, I used three arrays to remove information as below:

```
class student(object):
  def __init__(self):
        self.c=0
        self.x=[]
        self.y=[]
        self.z=[]
    def vrod(self):
        self.x.append(input("enter name:"))
        self.z.append(int(input("enter #:")))
        self.y.append(int(input("enter score:")))
        self.c+=1

    def remove(self):
        self.p=int(input("enter student number:"))
        for self.i in range(len(self.x)):
            if self.p==self.z[self.i]:
                del(self.x[self.i])
                del(self.y[self.i])
                del(self.z[self.i])
    def report(self):
        for self.i in range(len(self.x)):
            print("name:",self.x[self.i],"st number:",self.z[self.i],"score:",self.y[self.i])


a=student()
while True:
    print("o=1:::add  ","o=2:::remove  ","o=3:::report  ","o=4:::exit")
    o=int(input("enter menu:"))
    if o==1:
       a.vrod() 
    elif o==2:

        a.remove()
    elif o==3:
        a.report()
    elif o==4:
        break
```

Again, I have problem with removing.As I enter numbers for removing, I get error as it is

> "if self.p==self.z[self.i]: IndexError: list index out of range".

Do you know what is the problem?

Which of them is more common? Writing a code with one array or three arrays.

Comment: Rule #1: give your variables meaningful names. This makes absolutely no sense as it is.

Comment: You're changing the length of a list while iterating over its indices. This is a **very bad idea**.

Comment: `z` has less elements than the current value of `i`

Comment: can you explain a bit more?Do you have solution?

Comment: Take a list `l = [0, 1]`. Set `i = 0`. Remove the element `del l[i]`. Increment `i += 1`. Now what is `i`? What is `l`? And what is `l[i]`?

Comment: jonrsharpe, suppose we have [1,2,3]. then, I enter 2 for p. firstly, i=0 and then 1==z[0] is not true. Again we will have 1==z[1] which is true and will have del x[1], del y[1] and del z[1]. what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're iterating over a loop and making changes to the list you're looping over while doing so. The impulse to do so is understandable, but unless you know what you're doing you should just avoid that. Anyway, lets take a look at what you're doing and how it impacts the loop and the list. Removing the extra stuff, the basics of it is this:

```
def remove(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        del(x[i])
        #Do other stuff
```

Now, lets give x some dummy values:

```
values = [4, 10, 23]
remove(values)
```

Now before we run the code, it's useful to know exactly what `range(len(x))` does, which is that it creates a new list that counts from `0` in increments of `1` (as long as nothing else is specified), and the amount of elements in it is equal to the length of the input list.

so lets feed `range(len(x))` our dummy value, `[4, 10, 23]`. The output is `[0, 1, 2]`

So if we go back to the for loop, this means that **almost no matter what** we do after the for loop is initialized, the for loop will count through this newly generated list, `[0, 1, 2]`. So with all of that out of the way, lets actually run the code line by line.

```
#first loop
#i = 0
del(x[0])
#x=[10, 23]
```

This deletes element 0 in the list, 4, which leaves us with `x=[10, 23]` Notice how since deleting this element, `10` and `23` switched places, and the list became 1 element shorter. Still the list we're looping over remains the same, `[0, 1, 2]` So lets see what happens next loop:

```
#second loop
#i = 1
del(x[1])
x = [10]
```

This deletes element `1` in the list, which is now `23`, leaving us with `x=[10]`. Notice how we just skipped an element we wanted to delete. Not a good sign. Any who, onto the final loop:

```
#third loop
#i = 2
del(x[2])
#IndexError
```

This is where Python sees a clear error and is forced to stop the program. at this point if you do `len(x)` it will return `1`, which means the last element in the list will have the reference, `0`. So when you then call `del(x[2])`, you're essentially telling Python to remove something non-existent.

So, now we have a decent overview of what went wrong, then how do we make this work? One way, would be to turn the solution on its head. Instead of deleting elements we want to get rid of in the for loop, we make a new list and add the elements to that list that we want to keep. I removed the `if` statement in the above example for simplicitys sake, but I'm adding it back in the solution to demonstrate how to do this when you don't necessarily want to remove all elements in a list. I'm not going to walk through it like I did with the previous example, so look at it and analyze it and try to understand why it works the way it works (the "#condition where you want to delete:" is pseudocode, so don't interpret that directly):

```
def remove(x):
    rest_x = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if not #condition where you want to delete:
            rest_x.append(x[i])
    return rest_x
```

I hope this was helpful